# When does $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|?$

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products, proof-verification

> Let $(V_\mathbb R,\langle,\rangle)$ be an inner product space. I'm  trying to see for $x,y\in V$ when does $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|?$

- Let $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$

  Squaring both sides, $\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle+2\|x\|.\|y\|\\\ge\langle x,x\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle+2\langle x,y\rangle\\=\langle x,x\rangle+\langle x,y\rangle+\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle\\=\langle x,x+y\rangle+\langle x+y,y\rangle...(*)\\\implies\langle x+y,x+y\rangle-\langle x,x+y\rangle\ge\langle x+y,y\rangle\\\implies0\ge\langle x,0\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle\text{ due to linearity}\\\implies y=0$

  Again from $(*),\langle x+y,x+y\rangle-\langle x+y,y\rangle\ge\langle x,x+y\rangle\\\implies 0\ge\langle x,x\rangle+\langle0,y\rangle\\\implies x=0$

---

*Where did I go wrong?*

Comment: Clearly your answer cannot be right. Think about the case of the triangle inequality in $\mathbb R$. We have $|1|+|1|=|2|$, but neither is zero.

Comment: I still can't find out any mistake in the lines of proof.

Comment: How did you get from "$\langle x+y,x+y\rangle-\langle x,x+y\rangle\ge\langle x+y,y\rangle$" to "$\langle y,0\rangle\ge\langle x,0\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle$"?

Comment: @wj32: I had made a mistake even though my findings are still unaffected. $\langle x+y,x+y\rangle-\langle x,x+y\rangle=\langle x+y,x+y\rangle+\langle x,-(x+y)\rangle=\langle 2x+y,0\rangle=0.$

Comment: @SritiMallick: You are confused. The inner product is a bilinear map, but that does NOT mean that $\langle a,b\rangle+\langle c,d\rangle=\langle a+c,b+d\rangle$.

Comment: oh no...!! $\langle a+c,b+d\rangle=\langle a,b+d\rangle+\langle c,b+d\rangle=\langle a,b\rangle+\langle a,d\rangle+\langle c,b\rangle+\langle c,d\rangle.$ Right?

Comment: @SritiMallick: Yes, it's like $(a+c)(b+d)=ab+ad+cb+cd$, not $(a+c)(b+d)=ab+cd$.

Comment: @wj32: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third line in your formulas can be written (if you use that $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y,x\rangle$) as $\langle x+y,x+y\rangle$. So you have equality in the inequality in your second line. This implies
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\|x\|\,\|y\|,
$$
i.e. equality in Cauchy-Schwarz. So $x$ and $y$ are colinear.

Regarding your mistake, the two sides of the inequality in your first "implies" are equal. So your second "implies" is wrong.

Comment: $\langle x+y,x+y\rangle-\langle x,x+y\rangle=\langle x+y,y\rangle\\\implies\langle 2x+y,0\rangle=\langle x,0\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle\\\text{Once again the same thing !!! I need further help.}$

Comment: No. That implication is false. I don't know how you think you are getting it, but it is false.

Comment: Note that the first equality in your comment is satisfied by all vectors $x,y$. So there is nothing you can conclude from that.

Comment: I've got to identify the misconception as I've shown in my last comment above in the question section.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $||x+y|| = ||x|| + ||y||$. Then we have
$$\begin{align*}
\langle x + y, x + y \rangle &= \langle x, x + y \rangle + \langle y, x + y \rangle\\
&= \langle x, x \rangle + 2\langle x, y \rangle + \langle y, y \rangle\\
||x+y||^2&= ||x||^2 + 2\langle x, y \rangle + ||y||^2\\
\end{align*}$$

But from the assumption we have $||x+y||^2 = (||x|| + ||y||)^2 = ||x||^2 + 2||x||\,||y|| + ||y||^2\\$. By the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), this means x and y are linearly dependent, and specifically $x=cy$ for $c\ge 0$ (notice the absolute value around the inner product in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality).

I just realized I never addressed your question. The first implication is incorrect, since $\langle x+y,x+y\rangle-\langle x,x+y\rangle=\langle y,x+y\rangle$. In a real inner product space, your "inequality" is an equality, and in a complex vector space it is not safe to assume inequality.

Comment: Just because $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent doesn't mean $\|x + y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$.  Consider $|1 - 1| < |1| + |-1|$

Comment: No, you missed my point: I am referring to the equality $\langle x, y \rangle = ||x||\,||y||$, which is a component of my proof. Let me know if this is still unclear. EDIT: Wait, I think I see what you are getting at...

Comment: You're saying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is an equality of $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent.  That's true, but that doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected. Must it be the case that the two vectors must be linearly dependent and their signs cannot disagree?

Comment: Let me know if you agree with my correction.

Comment: Yeah, or when either vector is $0$.

Comment: The results holds when one of the vectors is zero or when $y = cx$ for $c \ge 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is more instructive than requiring that "they be linearly dependent and inner product be positive". I changed that.