# Name for norm with property $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$.

Tags: soft-question, normed-spaces

Is there a name for a norm with property $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ ?

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435087/when-does-xy-x-y), but it doesn't seem to answer my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider $0 = || x + (-x)|| = ||x|| + ||-x|| = 2 ||x||$. Hence the norm is `trivial' - every vector has norm zero. This in turn implies that the vector space is trivial.

Comment: Obviously people are liking your answer, but could you please clarify: Are you saying such a norm is called a "trivial norm"?

Comment: Sure, or a `linear norm' - obviously it is not used very much.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is only a norm, in the sense that it satisfies homogeneity, triangle inequality, and separate points, when the vector space is trivial, i.e. when $V=\{0\}$.

Comment: As Hayden pointed out, this is only a norm if $V=\{0\}$, otherwise, this is simply proof that a norm with the propertiy requested does not exist for the particular vector space.